# Couldn't create table with foreign key in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys

My application could not run if run keep the code line `db.execSQL(createOrderTable);` and `db.execSQL(createOrderDetail);`, which create two tables with the foreign keys, get rid of them the app run OK.

this is what I have on the `onCreate()` method:

```
String createUserTable = "create table " + USER_TABLE +
            "(userID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "userName TEXT NOT NULL," +
            "phoneNumber INTEGER);";
    String createProductTable = "create table " + PRODUCT_TABLE +
            "(productID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "department TEXT,"+
            "name TEXT," +
            "price REAL," +
            "status NUMERIC);";
    String createOrderTable = "create table " + ORDER_TABLE +
            "(orderID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "FOREIGN KEY(userID) REFERENCES User(userID)," +
            "FOREIGN KEY(productID) REFERENCES Product(productID));";
    String createOrderDetail = "create table " + ORDER_DETAIL_TABLE +
            "(FOREIGN KEY(orderID) REFERENCES Order(orderID)," +
            "customerName TEXT," +
            "address TEXT," +
            "totalPrice REAL," +
            "quantity INTEGER);";
    db.execSQL(createUserTable);
    db.execSQL(createProductTable);
    db.execSQL(createOrderTable);
    db.execSQL(createOrderDetail);
```

This is what I have for `onUpgrade()`:

```
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + USER_TABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + PRODUCT_TABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ORDER_TABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ORDER_DETAIL_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
```

How can I create the other two tables now?? Anyone can help? Appreciate that!

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: `AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device emulator-5554: device offline` I get this, but I dont know if it is associated with the database or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not create a column userId and productId in createOrderTable query but tried to make a foreign key reference. Create a column first and then reference it.

Eg:

```
String createOrderTable = "create table " + ORDER_TABLE +
        "(orderID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        "userID INTEGER,"+
        "productID INTEGER,"+
        "FOREIGN KEY(userID) REFERENCES User(userID)," +
        "FOREIGN KEY(productID) REFERENCES Product(productID));";
String createOrderDetail = "create table " + ORDER_DETAIL_TABLE +
        "(orderID INTEGER,"+
        "customerName TEXT," +
        "address TEXT," +
        "totalPrice REAL," +
        "quantity INTEGER," +
        "FOREIGN KEY(orderID) REFERENCES Order(orderID));";
```

Comment: It still get the syntax error at the creating order table query. I tried to enable foreign key support with `db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");` but no result

Answer (score 1):

You have to define your userID and productID column first and then set foreign key on it.

```
String createOrderTable = "create table " + ORDER_TABLE +
        "(orderID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        " userID integer," +
        "FOREIGN KEY(userID) REFERENCES User(userID)," +
        "productID integer" 
        "FOREIGN KEY(productID) REFERENCES Product(productID));";
```